# Ubuntu 14.04 suddenly won't load the Unity GUI after an update

Tags: 14.04, boot, unity, gui

This follows up with a new twist to:
[Ubuntu 14.04 stopped booting suddenly](https://askubuntu.com/questions/617890/ubuntu-14-04-stopped-booting-suddenly)

The situation before the problem cropped up was a little different this time around (for one, I didn't mess around with LightDM beforehand): Late this afternoon/earlier this evening, I tried to install some updates on my system with the Software Updater.

Things seemed to go relatively well in that regard, but I also noticed that I was suddenly unable to open Opera normally as well as Unity failing to return search results for applications.  I then rebooted.  Wanting to check on things, I decided to go into the Recovery Manager.  I then ran `fsck` followed by the FailSafe Graphics mode.

Unfortunately, the computer failed to boot, so after about 2 or 3 minutes, I did a hard shutdown (power button), did another file check, and tried to start it normally.  That didn't work. After 5 minutes of waiting, I rebooted, and tried to load a previous version of the kernel.  That didn't work either.

As with last time, it does appear I can at least boot up the basic console, but the GUI just won't work. I even tried starting LightDM, which ended with the system telling me that it was already active.

So I'm left with an Ubuntu that is virtually totally useless to me, especially because I'm not an expert user.  Further complicating things is the fact that I'm not sure how I finally managed to get the system to work again the last time.

So, can anyone offer some help?

Comment: did you look at any of this solutions? http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it

Comment: Hi JoKeR. I had indeed looked around for solutions, but I didn't come across that exact article, to be honest(although I'm sure it would have been quite helpful!). As it turns out, though, I was able to fix the problem right around the same general time you posted this question(only I didn't see it until some time afterwards). Still, though, thanks for your help, and I'll bookmark that article in case I may need it. =)

Answer (score 1):

Okay, well, luckily enough, I was able to fix the problem early on, and I think I may now know what could have caused it, or at least contributed to it:

I had been running really low on disk space for some time (and sometimes had to save my downloads elsewhere), and when I was finally able to log in as a Guest (`startx` might have really helped here!) the system informed me that I had literally *no* disk space left.

After mucking around with Baobab a bit, I decided to go ahead and delete an old game that I was no longer playing, which gave me about 2 GB of free space; I also got rid of Steam as well.

Well, when I restarted the computer, I was able to boot up Ubuntu normally, without any issues whatsoever. And hopefully, this post will be helpful to other folks who may encounter a similar issue as well. =)

Comment: if you get stuck with no space left you can run `df -h` to be sure which part of the disk you want to free up and use the command `tune2fs` as instructed [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/249387/df-h-used-space-avail-free-space-is-less-than-the-total-size-of-home) by default Linux systems reserve 5% of disk space.